# Redirecting pages by IF-clause

Tags: php, redirect

I'm currently working on a small php project to teach me PHP, javascript, etc.

I've got a **index.php**, which is supposed to manage which site is being accessed.
I use **_GET** variables to do so.

If the **login_message** isn't set, **login.php** will be opened. (This works just fine.)
A few textboxes and a button are generated for the user input.

After the login has been processed, **index.php** will be called again and the **login_message** will be set.

After that the user should be redirected to **input.php** (if the login was successful and the correct **input_message** has been send) where he can input some other data.

The problem: **input.php** will be processed (if using the `header()` function), but the page won't refresh itself.

What I tried:

```
    header("Refresh:0 Location:input.php");

    echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
    echo 'window.location.replace("http://someurl/input.php")';
    echo '</script>';

    echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
    echo 'window.location.assign("http://someurl/input.php")';
    echo '</script>';

    echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
    echo 'window.location.href("http://someurl/input.php")';
    echo '</script>';
```

I'm guessing `header()` won't work because the HTML code has already been generated in **login.php**? index.php is completely free of whitespace or HTML code.

Comment: Remove the "Refresh" and only use `die(header("Location:input.php"));` without any javascript

Comment: Why are you using the same code over and over?

Comment: suggest you send more sample code...

Comment: @suvojit_007: i'm not using the same code over and over. these are different methods to redirect to a page, that i used.

Comment: @Lithilion: i tried that too. the php code will be executed, but the contents of the window won't refresh. It wil be stuck at the login.php

Comment: You should not send any html to the Client before the header

Comment: @Lithilion: I have to though, because of the login form created through login.php, right?

Answer (score 0):

Use `die(header("Location:input.php"));` without any javascript. Please notice the `die`or `exit`.

You have your login form. The user enters credentials and submits them. You get the credentials and proceed them. You decide to either redirect or show the login form again. Between getting the credentials and redirecting there is no html code necessary. Sending a header after html code does not work.

Comment: I tried that. The codes executes server-side. I can see the browser output in Eclipses debuger, but the page won't update. It still hangs at the login screen.

Comment: Could it be that this behavior is caused because i use jqueri to handle the button press that opens the php file which processes the login information?

$( "#btn_confirm" ).click(function() {
$.get("z_login.php",{name:$("#username_box").val(),pass:$("#password_box").val()}); });

Comment: What do you mean with browser output? Do you get the correct response header?

Comment: Eclipse runs the program on an internal browser. That's the browser output i mean.
The client -side browser (Chrome) doesn't update the site, the internal one eclipse uses does though.

How can i view the response header?

Comment: Can you maybe host it on a "real" server. Or at least xampp?

Comment: I am hosting it on a wamp server. Is this not a "real" server?